# Why is my Ubuntu installed on a FAT partition, and can I change it?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mac, ext4, fat32

I have a mac from 2006 and it is already not supported by the new Apple system, so I decided to install Ubuntu 13.04. I installed is alongside OSX, but I noticed that Ubuntu installed itself on a FAT partition. Why is Ubuntu using a FAT partition? Can I change it to EXT4 without losing my data and configuration?

Comment: Ubuntu can not be installed on a FAT partition so you will have to be more specific to glean the source of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Rod Smith is right, OSX disk manager did lye to me, he did show fat partition and other apps did show ext4.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that Zagroda is seeing the EFI System Partition (ESP), which is FAT. Another possibility is that an OS X utility is reporting partition types based on their type codes; Ubuntu 13.04 still uses the same type code for its data partitions as Windows uses for FAT and NTFS. A fix to libparted has been in the works for two years, but the libparted developers have been sluggish in pushing it out. The output of both `sudo parted /dev/sda print` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` would be informative. (The latter will require installing the `gdisk` package.)

If this is the case, it's because Disk Manager is using the GPT type code data, which Linux sets incorrectly. You can fix this by using `gdisk` from either Linux or OS X: Launch it, type `p` to view the partitions, and then use `t` to change the type code of any Linux partition shown as being of type 0700 so that it's of type 8300. When you're done, review your changes with `p` and then type `w` to save them.